# Why am I getting a 400 error when I'm trying to load a post using AJAX in WordPress?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

The goal: Display a post title and content using AJAX.

What I've done so far:

Load custom.js and localise AJAX in functions.php:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'custom_js', 'ajax_object', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        ));
```

Make a function to get the post's title and content in functions.php:

```
function my_load_ajax_content () {

    $pid        = intval($_POST['post_id']);
    $the_query  = new WP_Query(array('p' => $pid));

    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            $data = '
            <div class="post-container">
                <div id="postdata">
                    <h1 class="entry-title">'.get_the_title().'</h1>
                    <div class="entry-content">'.get_the_content().'</div>
                </div>
            </div>  
            ';

        }
    } 
    else {
        echo '<div id="postdata">'.__('Didnt find anything', THEME_NAME).'</div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();


    echo '<div id="postdata">'.$data.'</div>';
}

add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_load-content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
```

Do the AJAX stuff in custom.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {
        action: 'my_load_ajax_content ',            
        post_id: 17521  // << should grab this from input...

    }, function(data) {

        var $response   =   jQuery(data);
        var postdata    =   $response.filter('#postdata').html();

        jQuery('.stickithere').html(postdata);
    });
```

And finally give it a place to load on the page:

```
<div class="stickithere"></div>
```

I'm getting a 400 error, and I have no idea why but I'd guess it's something to do with localising AJAX, as that seems to have been the reason for most of my nightmares recently.

Comment: What does the error message tell you? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: What you mean by `localising AJAX`? Have you checked network tab if all information is set properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is where the problem is:
`add_action ( 'wp_ajax_load-content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );`. **load-content** - is the name of the action, passed by AJAX. But you're passing `action: 'my_load_ajax_content'`. So try to change your actions like this:

```
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_load_ajax_content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_my_load_ajax_content', 'my_load_ajax_content' );
```

Comment: Fantastic, that fixed it!  You wouldn't know how to make this work with custom post types would you?

Comment: Sure. You need to add `post_type => 'your_cpt'` to an array of args for WP_Query. More info here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters

Comment: Awesome.  So I just changed the_query to: `    $the_query  = new WP_Query(array(
        'p' => $pid,
        'post_type' => 'market',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'title', 
        'order' => 'ASC', 
        ));` and now it works!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)